# Get row which matched in each group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a sql query. I got some results from 2 tables below. Below results are good for me. Now I want those values which is present in each group. for example, A and B is present in each group(in each ID). so i want only A and B in result. and also i want make my query dynamic. Could anyone help?

```
| ID | Value |
|----|-------|
|  1 |     A |
|  1 |     B |
|  1 |     C |
|  1 |     D |
|  2 |     A |
|  2 |     B |
|  2 |     C |
|  3 |     A |
|  3 |     B |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following query, I have placed your current query into a CTE for further use.  We can try selecting those values for which every `ID` in your current result appears.  This would imply that such values are associated with every `ID`.

```
WITH cte AS (
    -- your current query
)

SELECT Value
FROM cte
GROUP BY Value
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ID) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM cte);
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple - you can do this in two ways at least. Group by letters (`Value`), aggregate IDs with `SUM` or `COUNT` (distinct values in `ID`). Having that, choose those letters that have the value for `SUM(ID)` or `COUNT(ID)`.

```
select Value from MyTable group by Value
having SUM(ID) = (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT ID) from MyTable)

select Value from MyTable group by Value
having COUNT(ID) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) from MyTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
      Value,
  Cnt = COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
  FROM T1
  GROUP BY Value
)
SELECT
Value
FROM CTE
WHERE Cnt = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM T1)
```